# Groupby Dataframe with Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 2D grid on which there is a path. I want to calculate the distances of each point of the grid to each point on the path, then do some groupby operations. I am using dask.dataframe for this however I'll explain it in terms of pandas because I don't think it is a dask issue.

The code is similar to this

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, x, sparse='True') 

path = np.random.rand(5, 2)

dists = []
for i in range(5):
    xd = xv-path[i,0]
    yd = yv-path[i, 1]
    d = np.sqrt(xd**2+yd**2)
    dists.append(d)

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(c) for c in dists], axis=1, keys=np.arange(5))
```

So the dataframe should be roughly like this

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grid distance to first point (100 x 100 dataframe) | Grid distance to second point (100 x 100 dataframe) | ... | ... | Grid distance to last point (100 x 100 dataframe) |

Now I want to calculate the maximum 'grid' from this dataframe. As in I want to get a 100 x 100 grid that represents the maximum values across all 5 points of the path. How can I do this?

I can't use the key word level because it is not supported in dask. However I can use df.columns.levels so I tried this (among many other things) and it didn't work

```
df.groupby(df.columns.levels[1]).max()
```

It returns a 100 x 500 dataframe which is not what I want.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify `level=1, axis=1` in `groupby` in order to group by the 2nd level of the column index (`axis=1`):

```
df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).max()

#           0          1          2   ...          97          98          99
#0    1.005712   0.805206   1.746326  ...   97.705173   98.715274   99.725375
#1    0.997070   1.208150   1.991410  ...   97.709861   98.719913   99.729967
#2    1.987666   2.101498   2.631042  ...   97.724989   98.734887   99.744790
#3    2.991336   3.068154   3.452485  ...   97.750554   98.760191   99.769837
#4    3.998246   4.056039   4.354026  ...   97.786546   98.795815   99.805101
#..        ...        ...        ...  ...         ...         ...         ...
#95  95.908388  95.910815  95.923878  ...  136.911072  137.633739  138.360005
#96  96.918485  96.920886  96.933814  ...  137.620549  138.339509  139.062090
#97  97.928582  97.930958  97.943753  ...  138.333762  139.049036  139.767948
#98  98.938679  98.941031  98.953695  ...  139.050656  139.762260  140.477523
#99  99.948776  99.951105  99.963640  ...  139.771172  140.479127  141.190758

#[100 rows x 100 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! 
So I am actually using another library for this that is built on pandas (dask dataframe). And this library does not have the level and axis keywords. Is there an alternative to what you suggested using just the indexing may be?

Comment: I'm not familiar with dask. Can you use pandas API for each partition of the dask dataframe (since dask dataframe is a collection of pandas dataframes under the hood) ? If yes, then you might be able to leverage this.

Comment: `dask` [`Aggregate` API](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html) might be what you needed. `dd.Aggregation` and use the above syntax as the `chunk` function, and `pd.concat` as the `agg` function could give the desired out.